# C/C++: Flush output before abnormal termination

Tags: c++, c, io, abort

Is there a need to explicitly flush output streams before calling `abort()` to avoid loss of output?

As I understand, with `stderr` there is no buffering, so calling `abort` after output to `stderr`/`cerr` should be ok. How about `stdout`/`cout`, or files that I open?

PS. I am working in Linux environment (if it matters).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's needed, but no, it may not be possible. If you're aborting from an async-signal context, calling `fflush` invokes undefined behavior. And in general, if the reason for calling `abort` is that you've detected inconsistent state in your program, there's a risk that stdio state is also corrupted, and that calling `fflush` is therefore unsafe.

In general, you should use `exit(1)` if you're terminating due to a condition that your program simply can't handle, and use `abort()` (without `fflush`) only when you have detected that your program invoked undefined behavior already,

Some more details:

The C standard *allows* an implementation to flush stdio streams as part of abort (C11 7.22.4.1:):

> Whether open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, open streams are closed, or temporary files are removed is implementation-defined.

However, this does not remove the requirement that `abort` work if called from a signal handler. Since, from a practical standpoint, it's usually impossible to flush buffers if `abort` is being called from a signal handler that interrupted stdio code that has the buffer in an inconsistent state, any implementation that attempts to use this allowance is likely to be buggy.

The current version of the Linux man page for `abort` incorrectly states:

> If the abort() function causes process termination, all open streams are closed and flushed.

A more correct statement of the current behavior would be that flushing is *attempted* but may fail or corrupt your data. This bug is presently in the process of being fixed in glibc (maybe the fix was already committed...?) according to this thread:

http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2013-05/msg00207.html

Comment: Does abort flush kernel buffers only, or stdio buffers in user space as well?

Comment: I am writing scientific code with MPI, and OpenMP threads. And if I encounter an error (typically user-input related, or some run-time computations related), I just want to quit my program. The reason I asked initial question is that I want my log files, which contain info and error descrption, to be flushed before my program terminates.
So from your answer follows, that I do not need to use `abort`, `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` will suffice?

Comment: @user2052436: As far as observable behavior, there is no such thing as a kernel buffer.

Comment: @user2052436, yes `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` should largely suffice to capture user errors. `abort` should only be used for more dramtic cases. e.g if you detect that your application runs completely out of memory.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I would argue that both `abort` and `exit(1)` are *bad behavior* for running out of memory. There's really no need to prefer `abort` here, since the program is in a state where it's still safe to call `exit`, but `abort` may be slightly less malicious since the calling code could perhaps catch `SIGABRT` and `longjmp` out of the bad code that's aborting on out-of-memory. :-) If you do use `abort` in non-UB situations like this, I think it's a good idea to call `fflush(0)` first.

Answer (score 0):

Stdout is buffered and so are the file you open with ofstream for example. You have to explicitly flush them using the flush manipulator

Comment: While this is true most of the time, it _is_ possible to open a file without buffering, and I believe it might even be possible to get an unbuffered `stdout` with some trickery.

Comment: Just use `setvbuf` or `setbuf` at the beginning of `main` to get unbuffered `stdout`.